# JPA Inheritance strategy JOINED

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been doing research lately on inheritance strategies of JPA.I decided to develop a new project and I decided that the most suitable strategy for me in this project is JOINED.My Entity hierarchy is like this:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String iban;

}
```

```
@Entity
public class DrawingAccount extends Account{


    public String drawingInfo;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{

    private String savingsInfo;
}
```

When I create a structure in this way, the database structure is created as I want. The common field (like IBAN) of subclasses is kept on the account table.Different fields on subclasses are kept in their own tables.But when I want to fetch only common fields ( like IBAN ) from database (SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT) it is sending a JOIN query to the tables of the subclasses for me.It's nice that it does this, but I only want to see the common areas.I only want the data for the ACCOUNT table in the database. Is there a way around this? I don't want it to send a JOIN query.There is nothing wrong with sending a JOIN, but in some cases like when i need this,  it should send a join query. When I don't want it to send a join query, it should not send JOIN.How can I do it?

Comment: You have to do a native query to avoid the join.

Comment: I wrote a native query like SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT, but this does not avoid the join

Comment: JPA inheritance follows java inheritance somewhat, but with a single representation for what constitutes an entity. So data cannot both be represented as an Account AND a DrawingAccount; it is one or the other. Querying on Account returns all data in that table, but JPA must build you DrawingAccount and SavingAccount instances. What you want is more along the lines of a view object, which would give you a flat look without inheritance and joining. Try maybe a constructor query: "Select new Account(a.id, a.iban) from Account a"